# How to call a method on image button click dynamically created in C Sharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a form which adds controls dynamically with user selecting the type of control he wants which is placed inside a placeholder .. Now i want add a Image Button Click event  to dynamically created Image Button .. Which I have no success in for the past two days .. I have tried using delegates n event handling which is a new concept for me .. 
I am using this to iterate and assign properties

```
 <
     void IterateThroughChildren(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
if (c.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton") &&
               c.ID == null)
            {
                ((ImageButton)c).ImageUrl = @"pictures/close-icon.png";
                ((ImageButton)c).ID = "Imagebtn" +count.ToString();

                ((ImageButton)c).Click += new ImageButtonClickEventHandler(UserControl1_ImageButtonClickEvent);            



            }>
```

And m using this delegate and event handlers to specify the function

```
  <public delegate void ImageButtonClickEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs args);
    public event ImageButtonClickEventHandler ImageButtonClickEvent;

    private void imageButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageButtonClickEvent != null)
        {
            ImageButtonClickEvent(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void UserControl1_ImageButtonClickEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        CreateRadioButtons(sender , args);
    }>
```

**

> I would also like to know other methods of calling a function on
>   dynamically created conlrols ..

**

Thanks in advance for any kind of assistant ..
here is the complete code ..

```
    <using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int count = 1;
    static int m = 0;
    static int n = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnAddControl.Visible = false;
        btnAddText.Visible = false;
    }

    void IterateThroughChildren(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox") &&
                  c.ID == null)
            {
                ((TextBox)c).ID = "txtQ" + count.ToString();
                ((TextBox)c).Text = "Add Text Here" + count.ToString();
                ((TextBox)c).Columns = 90;
                ((TextBox)c).Focus();
                 //((TextBox)c).TextChanged = "CreateRadioButtons()";
               // ((TextBox)c).Attributes["onclick"] = "this.CreateRadiobuttons()";
                //((TextBox)c).TextChanged();
                    //+= CreateRadioButton;                
                //((TextBox)c).Focus = CreateRadioButtons();

                count++;
            }
            if (c.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton") &&
               c.ID == null)
            {

            }
            if (c.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton") &&
               c.ID == null)
            {
                ((ImageButton)c).ImageUrl = @"pictures/close-icon.png";
                ((ImageButton)c).ID = "Imagebtn" +count.ToString();
                ((ImageButton)c).Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(_Default_Click);
                ((ImageButton)c).Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(CreateRadioButtons);

            }
            if (c.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label") &&
                 c.ID == null)
            {
                ((Label)c).Text = count.ToString() + ".";
            }

            if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                IterateThroughChildren(c);
            }
        }
    }

    void _Default_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateRadioButtons(sender,e);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected void abc_acb( object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
    }

    protected void CreateRadioButtons(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
        {
            btnAddControl.Visible = true;
            m++;

            // now, create n TextBoxes, adding them to the PlaceHolder TextBoxesHere
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {

                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new RadioButton());
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new ImageButton());
                LiteralControl literalBreak3 = new LiteralControl("<br />");
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literalBreak3);
                LiteralControl literalBreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literalBreak);
                LiteralControl literalBreak2 = new LiteralControl("<br />");
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literalBreak2);
            }
            EventHandler eh = new EventHandler(CreateRadioButtons);
            TextBox Mytextbox = new TextBox();
            Mytextbox.ID = "123";
            Mytextbox.Columns = 90;
            Mytextbox.AutoPostBack = true;
            Mytextbox.Text = "Click to create another option";
            Mytextbox.TextChanged += eh;
            //Mytextbox.TextChanged += CreateRadioButtons;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new RadioButton());
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Mytextbox);
            LiteralControl literalBreak4 = new LiteralControl("<br />");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literalBreak4);
            LiteralControl literalBreak5 = new LiteralControl("<br />");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literalBreak5);

            // now, set the Text property of each TextBox
            IterateThroughChildren(this);
        }

    }
    protected void CreateTextBoxes(object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        btnAddText.Visible = true;


        if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
        {
            n++;

            // now, create n TextBoxes, adding them to the PlaceHolder TextBoxesHere
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                TextBoxesHere.Controls.Add(new Label());                
                TextBoxesHere.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
                TextBoxesHere.Controls.Add(new ImageButton()); 
                LiteralControl literalBreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");
                TextBoxesHere.Controls.Add(literalBreak);
                LiteralControl literalBreak1 = new LiteralControl("<br />");
                TextBoxesHere.Controls.Add(literalBreak1);

            }

            // now, set the Text property of each TextBox
            IterateThroughChildren(this);
        }

    }


    protected void ddlSelectControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string a = ddlSelectControl.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (a == "0")
        {
            CreateRadioButtons(sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            CreateTextBoxes(sender ,e);

        }

    }

}
>
```

Comment: How are you creating them ? these controls will have to be re created for every postback

Comment: Image button have "ImageClickEventArgs" not "EventArgs"..

Comment: I am using the object to create new text box , image controls yeahthey are being recreated actually i was trying to form google doc form type functionin

Comment: So what is your problem?Is it "not firing" when you click the imagebutton or you can't even run it because of some errors?

Comment: yes it is not firing because m creating the control in Createradiobutton() and defining its click property and id in iteratethrougcontrol() ... it works if i give all of the controls in 1 place on another page separately like this ..

Comment: <ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
        img.ID = "img";
        img.AlternateText= "ImageButton";
        img.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(img_Click);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(img);
        
    }
    protected void img_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "img",
        "<script type = 'text/javascript'>alert('ImageButton Clicked');</script>");
    }>

Comment: Why do you have these two together I think `_Default_Click` is enough `((ImageButton)c).Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(_Default_Click);                 ((ImageButton)c).Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(CreateRadioButtons);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to get an image button to work on click is this ..

```
}
protected void img_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "img",
    "<script type = 'text/javascript'>alert('ImageButton Clicked');</script>");
}>
```

However in my case i am creating the button in CreateRadiobutton so on click the page load function is called therefore the property needs other solution ..

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what is *actually* happening, but your subscription code would be much better as (assuming .NET 3.5, so you can use LINQ):

```
foreach (ImageButton button in parent.Controls
                                     .OfType<ImageButton>()
                                     .Where(c => c.ID == null))
{
    button.ImageUrl = @"pictures/close-icon.png";
    buttonID = "Imagebtn" + count;

    button.Click += new UserControl1_ImageButtonClickEvent;
}
```

Note that that will only iterate over the controls *directly* under `parent`. If there are other container controls, you may need to recurse through those, e.g.

```
foreach (CompositeControl container in parent.Controls
                                             .OfType<CompositeControl>())
{
    IterateThroughChildren(container);
}
```

It's possible that that was what was actually wrong... but you haven't said what you've actually observed to be happening, which makes it harder to help you...

Comment: the button is dynamically created .. and i dont know how to call the function  on click of the dynamically created control .. i tried the above butit does not work properly or as i am new to c sharp syntax problem can be there ..

Answer (score 1):

In `CreateTextBoxes()`

```
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
             ImageButton iM = new ImageButton();//
             TextBoxesHere.Controls.Add(new Label());
             TextBoxesHere.Controls.Add(new TextBox());                 
             TextBoxesHere.Controls.Add(iM );                           
             LiteralControl literalBreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");                 
             TextBoxesHere.Controls.Add(literalBreak);                 
             LiteralControl literalBreak1 = new LiteralControl("<br />");                 
             TextBoxesHere.Controls.Add(literalBreak1);              
 }
```

In `CreateRadioButtons()`

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)                      
{  
            ImageButton iM = new ImageButton();//
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(iM);                          
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new TextBox()); 
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new ImageButton()); 
            LiteralControl literalBreak3 = new LiteralControl("<br />");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literalBreak3);                          
            LiteralControl literalBreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literalBreak);                          
            LiteralControl literalBreak2 = new LiteralControl("<br />");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literalBreak2);                      
}
```

Can you try the above code after omitting `c.ID == null` and `((ImageButton)c).ID = "Imagebtn" +count.ToString();`?That is just what I would try.